# PHP & (амперсанд) перед функцией

Tags: php

Зачем использовать & перед функцией
как пример
`function &load_class($class, $directory = 'libraries', $param = NULL)`

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676897/what-does-it-mean-to-start-a-php-function-with-an-ampersand#:~:text=An%20ampersand%20before%20a%20function,by%2Dreference%20to%20increase%20performance.

Comment: смотрите документацию: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php